# Is this a bug in Visual Studio 2010 compiler?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

```
DateTime? date = null;
string tmp = "a" + "(" + date ?? "blablabla" + ")";

Console.WriteLine(tmp);
```

This will print something close to: `'a ('`.

Is this a bug with `null-coalescing operator`?
If I put `date ?? "blablabla"` in parenthesis, it is underlined as error.

Comment: Don't surround `date ?? "blablabla"` with braces, but with parenthesis, and let us know if that changes something.

Comment: "is this a compiler bug?" 99.99% of the time the answer is **no**.

Comment: I've only ever found a single compiler bug, and that was 20 years ago. And that one was easy to confirm in that a call was compiled into malfunctioning code in one version of that specific compiler yet behaved differently (and correctly) in both the prior and subsequent versions. This is not a case like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you should [*always* assume it's *your* fault](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html), not the compiler's fault; [`select` isn't broken](http://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips). Do you honestly think the Visual Studio 2010 implementation of the `??` operator hasn't been battle tested? When you encounter something that doesn't match your expectations, check your expectations. Get out the manual, and make sure that *you* understand *exactly* what is suppose to happen. In this case, open the language specification.

If you proceed to §1.4 of the [specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7029), you'll see a table that groups operators into precedence groupings; you can also find it [online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323.aspx). In particular, the null coalescing operator `??` is near the *bottom*, above only the lowly conditional ternary operator and assignments and `=>`. It is *below* the additive operator. Thus, your *statement*

```
string tmp = "a" + "(" + date ?? "blablabla" + ")";
```

is treated by the compiler as

```
string tmp = (("a" + "(" + date) ?? ("blablabla" + ")"));
```

I'm not going to be completely pedantic and *also* parenthesize the first additive expression<sup>1</sup>. Since the left-hand-side of the expression in that statement is *never* null, of course it *always* assigns `"a("` (or `"a("` + `date.ToString()` when `date.HasValue` is true) to `tmp`.

The *main* point is that *you* had an incorrect expectation as to what should be happening that *you* should have verified against the manual.

> If I put `date ?? "blablabla"` in parenthesis, it is underlined as error.

Of course it is. Did you even read the error message? It probably tells you that you can't do `??` on a `DateTime?` and a `string` because there are no implicit conversions between `DateTime?` and `string` in either direction. This, too, is covered in the language specification; see §7.13. You have to read this message and *respond* to it. To get something *semantically* equivalent to what you're *trying* to express, you'll have to resort to the conditional ternary operator:

```
date.HasValue ? date.ToString() : "blablabla"
```

and then wrap that whole thing in parentheses because the conditional ternary operator has *very* low precedence.

Finally, I find a correctly parenthesized version of your code rather ugly, not fun to read, and probably not enjoyable to maintain. Just make it simple, please:

```
var tmp = String.Format("a({0})", 
                       date.HasValue ? date.ToString() : "blablabla");
```

Now it is *so* clear what is going on and what is going to happen. I don't have to *think* to understand it. Save your thinking for the difficult problems you'll encounter.

<sup>1</sup>:  Be careful. We would need to add in a method call to `date.ToString` (which has the highest precedence) before attempting to correctly figure out what is evaluated first.

Comment: This answer is much better than selected one.

Answer (score 8):

[Null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) `??` has a lower precedence than the `+` operator, so your code is equal to

```
string tmp = ("a" + "(" + date) ?? ("blablabla" + ")");
```

Since everything in the `+` operation with a string produces a string (by calling `.ToString()` on all non-string operands), your code will always produce the `"a("` string.

Comment: "precedence" over "priority", I'd say.

Comment: It's also important to note that a non-null string concatted with null results in the non-null string, rather than an error or null, so the `+ date` is effectively a no-op.

Answer (score 3):

Here just another version:

```
DateTime? date = null;
string tmp = string.Format("a({0})", 
                           date.HasValue ? date.ToString() : "blablabla");
```

I really love `string.Format` instead of concatenation.

Comment: I do too; I for all but the simplest expressions it leads to more readable and maintainable code.

Answer (score 2):

`"blablabla"` is not a date, so you can't use is to set a `date?`.

---

```
string tmp = "a" + "(" + date ?? "blablabla" + ")";
```

is equivalent to

```
string tmp = ("a" + "(" + date) ?? ("blablabla" + ")");
```

which is where your `a(` is coming from.

---

However

```
string tmp = "a" + "(" + (date ?? DateTime.Now) + ")";
```

or similar should work.

Answer (score 1):

From [C# Language Specification §1.4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7029)

> The following table summarizes C#’s operators, listing the operator
>   categories in order of precedence from highest to lowest. Operators in
>   the same category have equal precedence.

It says [*Additive* operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktz6ya2s.aspx) is higher precedence than null coalescing operator.

So, [`+`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1a63xkz.aspx) has higher precedence than [`??`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) and that's why `"blablabla" + ")"` expression works first.

And since `date` is `null`, the statement works like;

```
string tmp = "a" + "(" + null;
```

And normally result will be `a(`

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because `date` isn't a string and the `??` operator can't determine a common base type for `date` and `"blablabla"`. Try `(date.ToString() ?? "blablabla")`. But this won't satisfy your need either because `date.ToString()` will never be `null`.

```
string tmp = "a" + "(" + (date ?? DateTime.Now) + ")";
```

should work.

Comment: Plus, if `date` is `null`, and you attempt to call `ToString()` on it, you'll get a `NullReferenceException` (Hmm, that may only be true for nullable types that are reference types--and `DateTime` is a ValueType, so the nullable for it would be the value-type `Nullable<T>` instead of the class-based one--so maybe this would be ok?).

Comment: @fourpastmidnight Your suggestion is correct - ((DateTime?)null).ToString() executes without errors.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug with the null-coalescing operator.

It's [operator precedence](http://en.csharp-online.net/ECMA-334%3a_14.2.1_Operator_precedence_and_associativity):

```
"a" + "(" + date ?? "blablabla" + ")"
```

is the same as:

```
("a" + "(" + date.ToString() ) ?? ( "blablabla" + ")" )
```

and `("a" + "(" + date.ToString() )` is not null.